# Hay alguna manera de llenar un array para json automaticamente

Tags: php, json, mysqli

hago una consulta mysql, los datos de la tabla los cargo cada uno en una variable y luego cada uno los devuelvo en json, me resulta tedioso hacer campo por campo, hay alguna manera de hacerlo automáticamente?

este es el código.

```html
<?php
if (!function_exists('Conectarse')) {
include "../Conexion/Conexion.php";
}
$conexion=Conectarse();

$NroSol=$_POST["NroSol"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE txt_nro_solicitud = '$NroSol'";
$datosProv = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($datosProv)!=0){
  while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($datosProv)) {

    $cuit = $registro['cuit'];
    $conv_multi = $registro['conv_multi'];
    $email = $registro['email'];
    $nombres = $registro['nombres'];
    $domicilio = $registro['domicilio'];
    $localidad = strtoupper($registro['localidad']);
    $tel = $registro['tel'];
    $cp = $registro['cp'];
    $entidad = strtoupper($registro['entidad']);
    $dtos_filiat = strtoupper($registro['dtos_filiat']);
    $ap_pat = strtoupper($registro['ap_pat']);
    $ap_mat = $registro['ap_mat'];
    $ap_interesado = $registro['ap_interesado'];//
    $nom_interesado = $registro['nom_interesado'];//
    $dni_int = $registro['dni_int'];
    $est_civil_int = $registro['est_civil_int'];
    $domicilio_int = strtoupper($registro['domicilio_int']);
    $localidad_int = $registro['localidad_int'];
    $provincia_int = $registro['provincia_int'];
    $cp_int = $registro['cp_int'];
    $tel_int = $registro['tel_int'];
    $cel_int = $registro['cel_int'];
    $ap_cony = $registro['ap_cony'];//
    $nom_cony = $registro['nom_cony'];//
    $dni_cony = $registro['dni_cony'];
    $ap_aut = $registro['ap_aut'];////////
    $nom_aut = $registro['nom_aut'];
    $cargo_aut = $registro['cargo_aut'];
    $tipo_doc_aut = $registro['tipo_doc_aut'];
    $documento_aut = $registro['documento_aut'];
    $ap_aut2 = $registro['ap_aut2'];
    $nom_aut2 = $registro['nom_aut2'];
    $cargo_aut2 = $registro['cargo_aut2'];
    $tipo_doc_aut2 = $registro['tipo_doc_aut2'];
    $documento_aut2 = $registro['documento_aut2'];
    $ap_aut3 = $registro['ap_aut3'];
    $nom_aut3 = $registro['nom_aut3'];
    $cargo_aut3 = $registro['cargo_aut3'];
    $tipo_doc_aut3 = $registro['tipo_doc_aut3'];
    $documento_aut3 = $registro['documento_aut3'];
    $ap_aut4 = $registro['ap_aut4'];
    $nom_aut4 = $registro['nom_aut4'];
    $cargo_aut4 = $registro['cargo_aut4'];
    $tipo_doc_aut4 = $registro['tipo_doc_aut4'];
    $documento_aut4 = $registro['documento_aut4'];
  }
  echo json_encode(array(
    "nombres"=>$nombres, 
    "domicilio"=>$domicilio,
    "cuit"=>$cuit,
    "email"=>$email)

    "conv_multi"=>$conv_multi,
    "localidad"=>$localidad,
    "tel"=>$tel,
    "cp"=>$cp,
    "entidad"=>$entidad,
    "dtos_filiat"=>$dtos_filiat,
    "ap_pat"=>$ap_pat,
    "ap_mat"=>$ap_mat,
    "ap_interesado"=>$ap_interesado,
    "nom_interesado"=>$nom_interesado,
  );
}else {
  echo json_encode(array("nombres"=>"no hay datos", "domicilio"=>"no hay datos","cuit"=>"no hay datos","email"=>"no hay datos"));
}
?>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo asi:

    $data = [];
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $data['row1'] = $row['data'];
    }
     echo json_encode($data);

Comment: aunque para hacerlo automáticamente lo puedes hacer mediante un bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Ver Demo](http://goo.gl/9GI63n)**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($datosProv)!=0){

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($datosProv)) {

        $fetchArray[] = $registro;

    }
    echo json_encode(["fetch"=>$fetchArray]);

}else {
    echo json_encode(array("nombres"=>"no hay datos", "domicilio"=>"no hay datos","cuit"=>"no hay datos","email"=>"no hay datos"));
}
```

**INFO ADICIONAL**

Usa por favor sentencias preparadas de [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) o mejor aún, usa la interfaz de [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php), para evitar cualquier ataque ante una [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).